# pyd wrap_class example does not compile

Tags: d, pyd

I am fairly new to D and try to implement a python wrapper for my first code using the pyd framework. I follow the example code provided at http://svn.dsource.org/projects/pyd/trunk/raw_html/class_wrapping.html but the recipe for wrap_class seems to fail. My code snippet

```
import pyd.pyd;
import pyd.class_wrap;

class Foo {
    int m_i;

    this() { m_i = 0; }
    this(int j) { m_i = j; }
    this(int j, int k) { m_i = j + k; }

    int i() { return m_i; }
    void i(int j) { m_i = j; }

    void foo(char[] s) {
        import std.stdio;
        writefln(s, m_i);
    }

    Foo opAdd(Foo rhs) {
        return new Foo(m_i + rhs.m_i);
    }
}


extern(C) void PydMain() {
    module_init();

    // Call wrap_class
    wrap_class!(
        Foo,
        // Wrap the "foo" method
        Def!(Foo.foo),
        // Wrap the "i" property
        Property!(Foo.i),
        // Wrap the constructors.
        Init!(void function(int), void function(int, int))
    );
}
```

which is essentially copied form the example fails to compute with the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyd/infrastructure/pyd/class_wrap.d(526): Error: tuple index 0 exceeds 0
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyd/infrastructure/pyd/class_wrap.d(534): Error: template instance pyd.class_wrap.Init!(void function(int), void function(int, int)).Init.Inner!(Foo) error instantiating
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyd/infrastructure/pyd/make_wrapper.d(126):        instantiated from here: shim!(2LU, Foo)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyd/infrastructure/pyd/make_wrapper.d(136):        4 recursive instantiations from here: class_decls!(0u, Foo, Def!(foo), Property!(i), Init!(void function(int), void function(int, int)))
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyd/infrastructure/pyd/class_wrap.d(1483):        instantiated from here: make_wrapper!(Foo, Def!(foo), Property!(i), Init!(void function(int), void function(int, int)))
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyd/infrastructure/pyd/class_wrap.d(1476):        instantiated from here: _wrap_class!(Foo, "Foo", "", "", Def!(foo), Property!(i), Init!(void function(int), void function(int, int)))
pystochcalc.d(35):        instantiated from here: wrap_class!(Foo, Def!(foo), Property!(i), Init!(void function(int), void function(int, int)))
error: command 'dmd' failed with exit status 1
```

Does anyone have an idea what this error message tells me and how I can fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyd at dsource is outdated. Use pyd from GitHub - https://github.com/ariovistus/pyd . For examples check the [/examples](https://github.com/ariovistus/pyd/tree/master/examples) folder. Check the */examples/wrap* for an example which shows how to do these sorts of things.

Comment: I am having the same compilation following the example from github.